# Virtual Machine Performance on Hyper-V

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtual-machine, hyper-v

We converted successfully a Physical Machine (windows 2000 server sp4) to a Virtual Machine ( to run on Hyper-V ) with the follow methodology:

1. With the use of **VMware Converter version 3.0** we produce an image of Physical Machine ( vmdk file)
2. We use **vmdk2Vhd** tool to convert from vmdk to vhd with success
3. We load the image to a **Hyper-V** WIN 2008 R2

The only problem is that the CPU Usage for this server only (we have 7 others VMs in the same Hyper-V platform) is up to 60% all day. The server has 2 sql instance, 2 partitions (C: 4.9GB with 600Mb free space and E: 62GB with 6GB free space), 2 GB RAM.

How can we find out why only this VM needs so many CPU Usage?

Thank you for your assistance.

John.

Comment: Better suited for serverfault.com

Answer (score 2):

Joking?

- You upgarded the integartion components and use englighted interfaces for network?

> The server has 2 sql instance, 2
>   partitions (C: 4.9GB with 600Mb free
>   space and E: 62GB with 6GB free
>   space), 2 GB RAM.

Ah-.--- 2 sql instaces on 2gb ram?

> How can we find out why only this VM
>   needs so many CPU Usage?

Ignore it is a VM. Log into the server and start finding out waht that the CPU is busy with.

Comment: No, I am not joking. The machine used to operate OK with the same configuration ( as physical machine and 512 MB RAM ). We provided more VM RAM when we migrated to Hyper-V